# How to avoid of duplication overriding fields in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, duplicates, overriding, field

Inherited object create new filed instead of `Override` it.

Let's Say `CredentialMessage` extend from `Message`

```
open class Message(
        @SerializedName("l") open val label: String
){
        override fun toString(): String {
                return label
        }
}

class CredentialMessage(
    @Transient override val label: String,
    @SerializedName("u") open val userName: String,
    @SerializedName("p") open val password: String
): Message("\uD83D\uDD12" + label) //
```

Simple example of `CredentialMessage` looks like this

```
val message = CredentialMessage("Barev","user","pass")
```

when I print the label of message instead of "Barev" i have got an "Barev"

```
println(message.label) // "Barev"
```

Debug shows there are two label.
The first one is `label`, and the second one is `Message.label`

[image]

**And no any way to access `Message.label`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After decompiling the existing source code I found the answer.
`override` keyword generate exact the same field. After removing  `override` keyword the problem solved.

```
class CredentialMessage(
    label: String,
    @SerializedName("u") open val userName: String,
    @SerializedName("p") open val password: String
): Message("\uD83D\uDD12" + label) //
```

Comment: You've also removed the `val`; that's probably the major factor.  (Without it, `label` is just a constructor parameter, not a class property, so doesn't interfere with the superclass property.  I'm still not sure why it did before, though.)